# Phonegap cannot display php content retrieved via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, cordova

I have a simple PHP as below and an HTML file (which is the file supplied by phonegap-index.html page) with some jQuery code to get content from the PHP, which is hosted on localhost. Everything work fine in the browser but in phonegap I can only see the html codes, i.e., I don't see the content receied form PHP via jQuery. I have added my ip address and the localhost to config.xml file of phonegap for whitelisting. The jQuery callback is set to JSONP. Phonegap server is installed on ubuntu which is running fine an phonegap app/client is installed on iPhone 5s which shows any simple html content but not php contents received via jQuery.

I believe the problem is with phonegap but I have spend three days on it and cannot find what I am doing wrong.

Here are my files:
index.html

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery to get data from gettext.php page -->
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON('http://localhost/hello/gettext.php', function(jsonp){
      $("#txtHint").html(JSON.stringify(jsonp, null, 2));
      });
   });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <br /><br /><br />
   <div class="app">
       <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
       <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
           <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
           <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
       </div>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      app.initialize();
   </script>
   <!-- this section is populated by jQuery -->
   <p>php content received via jQuery: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Here is my gettext.php page

```
  <?php
   header('content-type: application/jsonp; charset=utf-8');
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   echo json_encode("Hello World!");
   ?>
```

Here is the specific section of config.xml file for whitelisting

```
<access origin="*" />
   <access origin="http://127.0.0.0/hello2/gettext.php" />
   <access origin="http://localhost/hello2/gettext.php" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
   <allow-intent href="http://localhost/hello2/gettext.php" />
   <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
   <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
   <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
   <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
   <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
   <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
   <platform name="android">
     <allow-intent href="market:*" />
   </platform>
   <platform name="ios">
     <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
     <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
   </platform>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works in the browser but not on the phone as you're connecting to localhost. `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is just a hostname that can be used to access network services running on that host.

Your php server isn't running on your iPhone, so trying to connect to `localhost` from the phone doesn't make sense. You need to connect to the externally available address of your server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sam. I can access the localhost on my machine from iPhone browser  but if I use the ip address  192.168.0.9 then I can access the gettext.php from my iPhone. The problem, which doesn't make sense to me, is that why the HTML content of my PHP file that is hosted on ubuntu is displayed in my iPhone browser but the PHP message that retrieved via jQuery is ignored? If I can see the HTML contents hosted on my localhost server from iPhone then why the PHP message is not displayed.